Retrieving a 2D array of Filtered Data in Google Sheets
I’m working on a Google Sheets project where I’ve created a custom menu. I want to run a specific function from this menu, but only on the data that is currently visible after the user applies a filter. How can I achieve this?
I’ve already created a custom menu using Google Apps Script.
The function I want to run iterates over each column in the spreadsheet than auto fills place holders in Google Docs.
I want this function to return a 2D array containing the data only in the the rows that are visible after the user applies a filter using the built-in filter feature in Google Sheets.
How can I ensure that my custom menu function works exclusively on the filtered data?
Here is my code so far:
 function createDocsFromSheet() {
     const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     const templateDocId = 'my Doc ID'; 

     const filter = sheet.getFilter();

     const data = filter.getRange().getValues();
     const headers = data[0]; 

     const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateDocId);
     const copy = templateDoc.makeCopy();

     const newFileName = "New Document Name";

     copy.setName(newFileName);

     const copyId = copy.getId();

    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

     for (let columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < headers.length; columnIndex++) {
  
         const header = headers[columnIndex];
         const columnData = data.map(row => row[columnIndex]);

         for (let i = 1; i < columnData.length; i++) {
             const placeholder = `{{${header}${i}}}`;
             const value = columnData[i];
             doc.getBody().replaceText(placeholder, value);
         }
     }
 }

after searching online I found out that it is not possible to call getValuse() on getFilter.
